# Different size images in horizontal List view / Grid view with fix height and dynamic width in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a horizontal **ListView** or **GridView** with fix height of images but **width of image should be dynamic**.

Below is the code witch I am trying to do but not able to get expected output. I have also added screenshot of design which illustrate the expected output

> With List View

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';


class ViewPager extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _ViewPager();
}

class _ViewPager extends State<ViewPager> {

  static final exercise_image1 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l";
  static final exercise_image2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          _imagesList(images: [exercise_image1, exercise_image2]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget _imagesList({List<String> images}) {

    return Container(
      width: double.maxFinite,
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          _imageListItem(imagePath: images.first),
          _imageListItem(imagePath: images.last),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

  Widget _imageListItem({@required String imagePath}) {

    return CachedNetworkImage(
      width: 200, // I want this to be according to the image width
      imageUrl: imagePath,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }

}
```

[image]

> With Grid View

Same issue with Grid View, we set height of the grid view but not able to give dynamic width to the image

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';


class ViewPager extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _ViewPager();
}

class _ViewPager extends State<ViewPager> {

  static final exercise_image1 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l";
  static final exercise_image2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: _imagesList(images: [exercise_image1, exercise_image2]),
        ),
      ),
    );


  }


  Widget _imagesList({List<String> images}) {

    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 1,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        _imageListItem(imagePath: images[0]),
        _imageListItem(imagePath: images[1]),
      ],
    );

  }

  Widget _imageListItem({@required String imagePath}) {

    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imagePath,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }

}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for flutter_staggered_grid_view.

Comment: I have tried that as well but that is also not dynamic(means not working as per image width).

Comment: Is `imageBuilder` part necessary for your case? Do you try to add more widgets below the builder? It seems it is the part that breaks the layout because the `Container` can't get the correct image size from its own decoration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is like so.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  static final exercise_image1 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l";
  static final exercise_image2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: _imagesList(images: [exercise_image1, exercise_image2]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _imagesList({List<String> images}) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        _imageListItem(imagePath: images[0]),
        _imageListItem(imagePath: images[1]),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _imageListItem({@required String imagePath}) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: imagePath,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use listview like this. It is giving the output you wanted.

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _imageListItem({@required String imagePath}) {
      return   CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imagePath,
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
      );
    }
    Widget horizontalList1 = new Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      height: 200.0,
      child:
      ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          _imageListItem(imagePath: exercise_image1),
          SizedBox(width: 2,),
          _imageListItem(imagePath: exercise_image2),

        ],
      ),
    );
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              horizontalList1,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3686123 have you tried it out or need some more help?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are talking about is **Aspect Ratio**, you want it to be fit on the width.

In the image widget, set **fit** to **BoxFit.fitWidth** and the problem will be solved.

Read more about it [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html).

Comment: No it's not aspect ratio. I am talking about fix height with any width. In ratio widget will expand in width and height in same ratio. but in my case i just want to give fix height but width can be any

Comment: BoxFit.fitHeight -> (plz check code it's already der and i have tired this in lots of other way too)

Comment: Sorry for my Typo, it must be fitWidth and not Height

Comment: Its running code, it will be great if you can give a try to run

Comment: I didn't understand you. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ViewPager extends StatelessWidget {
  const ViewPager({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static final exerciseImages = [
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eDhXVJrNExRwi85pQGCOAwPYi7X-sA0l",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri",
    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1ifjpLw2ocBAIbEOIhsTtczf8dWuvexri",
    // add more image url here. anything you want.
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          // shuffled to make it a lot more dynamic. demonstration only
          child: _imagesList(images: exerciseImages..shuffle()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _imagesList({List<String> images}) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(), // just for coolness.
      itemCount: images.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return _imageListItem(imagePath: images[index]); // access each images by their index.
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _imageListItem({@required String imagePath}) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4), // add padding so the edges of the image is clearly distinguishable.
      child: CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: imagePath,
        placeholder: (context, url) {
          return Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 32, // properly size the loading indicators.
              width: 32, // properly size the loading indicators.
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also improved the structure of the code slightly. Made it more dynamic. The fix is that you don't put size at all in the `CachedNetworkImage` widget. Just give it a url and placeholder. Your code for the parent container with `height: 150` is fine. The cache network image will adapt to that height automatically.